# Numerical implementation of n-th derivative of f(x)?

Tags: c++, c, math, derivative, numerical-integration

I implemented a C++ code to numerically solve the n-th derivative of a function in a point x_0:

```
double n_derivative( double ( *f )( double ), double x_0, int n )
 {
  if( n == 0 ) return f( x_0 );
  else 
   {
    const double h = pow( __DBL_EPSILON__, 1/3 );
    double x_1 = x_0 - h;
    double x_2 = x_0 + h;
    double first_term = n_derivative( f, x_2, n - 1 );
    double second_term = n_derivative( f, x_1, n - 1);

    return ( first_term - second_term ) / ( 2*h );
   }
 }
```

I was wondering if this is for you a good implementation or if there can be a way to better write it in C++. The problem is that I noticed that the n-th derivative diverges for values of n higher than 3. Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: Perhaps you could implement one of these? https://math.stackexchange.com/q/130192

Comment: Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_differentiation for techniques

Comment: Note `1/3 == 0`

Comment: Obligatory question: do you actually *need* numerical differentiation, or are you only using it because you haven't been given the function `f` in a convenient form for some kind of exact differentiation?

Comment: If you are looking for feedback (and if your code functions correctly), [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) might be a better choice of venue. On the other hand, if the code does **not** function correctly (as suggested by "The problem is [...]"), then you should focus your question on the malfunction, giving a concrete case along with expected and actual output.

Comment: `pow( __DBL_EPSILON__, 1/3 );` won't work as expected, and would be very costly to calculate in every function call like that instead of storing in a static constant

Comment: @o11c I know the function shape and I just want to obtain its derivative in a point x_0

Comment: @phuclv what do you mean with "instead of storing in a static constant"?

Comment: @GianlucaBianco I mean as that. Store a constant in a static variable or even better a compile-time constant that's evaluated only once instead of every function call

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not a good implementation

At least these problems.

**Integer math**

Use FP math as `1/3` is zero.

`1/3` --> `1.0/3`

**Using the cube root optimal for `n==1`**

But not certainly other `n`.  [@Eugene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70659635/numerical-implementation-of-n-th-derivative-of-fx/70660299#comment124913100_70660299)

**Wrong epsilon**

Below code is only useful for `|x_0|` about 1.0.  When `x_0` is large, `x_0 - h` may equal `x_0`.  When `x_0` is small, `x_0 - h` may equal `-h`.

OP's +/- some epsilon is good for *fixed* point, but `double` is a *floating* point.

```
// Bad
const double h = pow( __DBL_EPSILON__, 1.0/3 );
double x_1 = x_0 - h;
```

A *relative* scaling is needed.

```
#define EPS cbrt(DBL_EPSILON) // TBD code to well select this 
if (fabs(x_0) >= DBL_MIN && isfinite(x_0)) {
  double x_1 = x_0*(1.0 - EP3);
  double x_2 = x_0*(1.0 + EPS);
  double h2 = x_2 - x_1;
  ...
} else {
  TBD_Code for special cases
}
```

**Invalid code**

`f` is `double ( *f )( int, double )`, but call is `f( x_0 )`

**Minor: confusing names**

Why `first_term` with `x_2` and `second_term` with `x_1`?

Comment: the `1.0/3` exponent is only optimal for n==1.

Comment: The step `DBL_EPSILON * SCALE` is way too small. A correct choice of the step is a trade-off between roundoff errors and truncation errors. W/o more info on the function, `pow(DBL_EPSILON, 1.0/3)` is recommended instead of `1024*DBL_EPSILON` (for n==1; even higher for n>1).

Comment: Nitpick: Use `cbrt(x)` instead of `pow(x, 1.0/3.0)`

Comment: @njuffa `cbrt()` it is.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica thanks, I understand some stuff, but not all. Can you please post a code in which you implement the derivative with your corrections? thanks.

Comment: @GianlucaBianco The corrections are already posted in the answer.  So we can narrow the issue, what parts did you understand?  Which part you did not?

Comment: What does it mean ```if (fabs(x_0) >= DBL_MIN && isfinite(x_0))``` and also ```TBD_Code for special cases```? Thanks.

Comment: @GianlucaBianco `fabs(x_0)` takes the absolute value of `x_0`.  Compare that  to `DBL_MIN`, which is the minimum _normal_ `double`.  Between `DBL_MIN`  and `DBL_TRUE_MIN` are the sub-normals and 0.0.  (e.g. 1e-309 to 1e-324).  With those wee numbers, code should use a coarser epsilon.    `isfinite(x_0)` test if  `x_0` is not infinite and not  a "not-a-number".  For your learner code, you can skip these aside from `x_0 == 0`.  For 0.0, try `cbrt(DBL_MIN)`.  0 is special and really has no easy general +/- h that is _best_.